# Notification similar to whatsapp

Tags: android, push-notification, whatsapp, toast

I have to implement this type of notification similar to whatsapp.

I have two questions to ask.

1)what kind of notification is it?

[image]

Toast??
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts

Expandable Notification
https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/expanded

2) is this type of notification an android standard or is it a personalization of samsung mobile phones?

Comment: Looks like personalisation to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is **Edge lighting notification** which are personalization of samsung mobile phones.

For more details please prefer below link

[Android samsung custom notification heads up view](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46847679/11158194)

https://support.google.com/android/thread/15430580?hl=en&msgid=15430580

I hope this can help You!

Thank You.

Comment: excellent answer thank you.
I have not found examples of development.
do you have any examples?
I use xamarin or alternatively android studio.
if I use this type of notification on devices other than samsung what happens?
Are they in error or are they displayed differently?

Comment: I am also finding but still not getting how it's generated.

Comment: maybe just set the importance of the notification channel to high. I'll try it tonight

Comment: No,It's different.This is own UI of Smasung.